# html multiple input fields

Tags: php, html, mysql, input

I am creating a new form for my jobsheet program for my workshop. I have a jobsheet work required form with 4 fields to input. These are named work1, work2, work3 and work4. It takes these and writes to the database table jobcardwork. This has two fields, jobcard and work. I want it to write only if the field is not empty as maybe not all 3 lines have text. My code is like this.

```
$a = array($work1, $work2, $work3, $work4); 

 foreach ($a as $b) 

 { 

 $sql6 = "INSERT INTO jobcardwork (Jobcard,Work)VALUES('2','$b')";
 $result6=mysql_query($sql6); 

 }
```

This works but will write even if there is nothing in the box. The result is.

```
id      jobcard   work
14      2    
15      2         linda
16      2         dan
```

as you can see, its written the first line and entered the jobcard number but there was no text in the box so it has left this null. Please help. Thanks. p.s I know mysql is old but I started writting it before mysqli and PDO. Sorry.

Comment: You'll need to add some conditional logic, so for example. If `$b != ""` then insert, otherwise do something else. Although you should probably clean the strings first, instead of directly inserting the `POST` data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution without iffing:

```
$a = array($work1, $work2, $work3, $work4); 
foreach (array_filter($a) as $b) { 
   $sql6 = "INSERT INTO jobcardwork (Jobcard,Work)VALUES('2','$b')";
   $result6=mysql_query($sql6); 
}
```

See https://www.php.net/array_filter

Comment: Hi. I tried your solution as well but it clears my form and does not do anything. Am I missing something?

Comment: The only difference between your and my code is the `array_filter()` call which will filter out empty strings, nulls and false values. You can debug the values with `var_dump(array_filter($a))` and `var_dump($sql6)` to get more insights.

Comment: Thanks to all that help on this site. You have all helped many times in the past and I am starting to understand this programming much more. I am a CNC machinist by trade so this is very alien to me. Thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be much more optimized and written more safe, but it is not the topic of this question, so your quick fix would look like this:

```
$a = array($work1, $work2, $work3, $work4); 
foreach ($a as $b) { 
  if($b!="") {
     $sql6 = "INSERT INTO jobcardwork (Jobcard,Work)VALUES('2','$b')";
     $result6=mysql_query($sql6); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I tried this but it clears my form and does not do anything. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to remove extra spaces, get rid of sql attacks and then check if text is still empty.

Check **mysql_real_escape_string** and **trim** method. Final code will look like this.

```
 $result = array();
 foreach ($a as $b) 
 { 
    $b = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($b));

    if($b != '')
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO jobcardwork (Jobcard,Work)VALUES('2','$b')";
        $result[] = mysql_query($sql); 
    }

 }
 var_dump($result);
```